# Detect Caller Name when I get Incoming call or Outgoing Call

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I wanted to fetch the call info when receiving or making a call inside my app.

Ex: If James is calling me. I should be able to print "James is calling me" inside my app, including when my app is in inactive state.

Is it possible to do that? I also want to access the state of the call and show a notification  until the call disconnects.

Comment: ohh.as per my knowledge, it is not possible to get name. CoreMobile only provide three states 1. Call is coming 2. Connected 3. Disconnected use CoreTelephony framework for above task.

Comment: Yea having the ability to gather caller/user information about their calls would get into the grey->black area of user privacy rather quickly.

Comment: Apple does not allow your app to directly access call information. See the linked question for what you are allowed to do.